# Python: How to mock path like `module.module.Class` by hacking sys.modules?

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, python-import

I am trying to unit test the code without changing the code itself.

**app/cannot_edit_this_file.py:**

```
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import messaging
....
aps = firebase_admin.messaging.Aps(
    alert=None,
    content_available=True,
    sound="default",
    custom_data={
        "title": title,
        "body": message,
        "notification_id": notification_id,
        "action_key": action_key
    }
)
```

**tests/tests.py:**

```
firebase_admin_module = __import__('tests.mock_firebase_admin')
sys.modules['firebase_admin'] = firebase_admin_module
messaging = __import__('tests.mock_firebase_admin.messaging')
sys.modules['firebase_admin.messaging'] = messaging
setattr(firebase_admin_module, 'messaging', messaging)
```

**tests/mock_firebase_admin/messaging.py:**

```
class Aps():

    def __init__(self,
                 alert=None,
                 content_available=True,
                 sound="default",
                 custom_data={}):
        print("Hello from mock Aps constructor!")
```

How do I mock it properly, so that executing `firebase_admin.messaging.Aps(...)` would create an instance of my mock Aps class? Right now that call raises an error:

```
'module' object has no attribute 'Aps'
```

Comment: `from unittest.mock import patch` then decorate your test with `@patch('firebase_admin.messaging.Aps')` This will inject a Mock object into your test function.

Comment: @KlausD. that fails: `AttributeError: <module 'tests' from '/path/to/project/tests/__init__.py'> does not have the attribute 'Aps'`. Slightly more detailed error message looks like this: `exc_info = (<type 'exceptions.AttributeError'>, AttributeError("<module 'tests' from '/path/to/project/tests/__init__.py'> does not have the attribute 'Aps'",), <traceback object at 0x108e9e640>)`

Comment: @KlausD. note that it looks for the Aps attribute in `project/tests/__init__.py` while it's actually defined in `project/tests/mock_firebase_admin/messaging.py`